# lock phone keys

Tags: windows-phone-7, locking, key

is it possible to lock all the phone keys in a windows phone 7 app (silverlight or xna)?

I need to create an app for toddlers and it would be great to lock all the keys so only adult can exit from app

Comment: +1 in sympathy for having to use Window phone 7.

Comment: This might be something for their suggestions forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to lock the main keys of the phone e.g. Start, Back, Search - the Back button is overridable but must only be used to dismiss a dialog or go to the previous screen - any other behaviour is not allowed and is enforced by Marketplace Submission criteria.

Comment: It's possible he may be allowed an exception for the back button behaviour if he applies for it during submission. But, as you mention, he's sunk on the other two.

Comment: While this is true, the certification guidelines are just that - Guidelines. It sounds like you have a good usecase for overriding Application_Exit with e.Cancel=True. When submitting a WP7 you can ask for a technical exception to any certification guideline. You might want to consider going down that route.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking at the wrong platform for your target audience. Why not develop an Xbox 360 game?